# How to put values to R Matrix cells?

Tags: r

I would like to put numerical values `ages` into the matrix cells, while now, I have them on x-ais

```
library("ggplot2")
library("reshape2")
mydata <- mtcars[, c(1,3,4,5,6,7)]
cormat <- round(cor(mydata),2)
melted_cormat <- melt(cormat)
ids = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6)
ages = c(11, 22, 33, 44, 55,66)
ggplot(data = melted_cormat, aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, fill=value)) +
        scale_x_discrete(labels = ids ) +
        scale_y_discrete(labels = ids)
```

Current output:

[image]

### My ideas

With `geom_text` but unsuccessful after the last scale

```
  + geom_text(aes(label = ages), size = 3)
```

Error in various attempts

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (4): label, x, y, fill
```

### Testing rawr's proposal in comment

```
+ geom_text(label = interaction(rep(ages, length(ages)), sep = ', '), size = 3)
```

Output with real-world data where you see that it repeats the first cell ID's Age for all columns; maybe, it could be enough to include the first age in the diagonal because otherwise we need two ages per cell which makes the matrix look crowded

[image]

### Trying to adjust the wiki answer to the real case

I cannot adjust the wiki answer and its `ifelse` to my real case where the following `geom-text` works

```
    geom_text(label = interaction(rep(ages, length(ages)), sep = ', ')) +
```

OS: Debian 8.5
R: 3.1.1

Comment: Functions need return values ... subset is for interactive use, i.e., not inside functions ...

Comment: try `geom_text(label = interaction(rep(ids, length(ages)), ages, sep = ', '), size = 3)` instead. you have 36 data points, you need 36 labels

Comment: is this a correlation matrix? or if the diagonal values are defined to be 1 (or 0) then they will all have a uniform color based on `value`

Comment: so only the diagonal labeled? `ggplot(data = melted_cormat, aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, fill=value)) + geom_tile() + geom_text(label = ifelse(melted_cormat$Var1 == melted_cormat$Var2, ages, ''))` it would probably be simpler to create a column with the labels you want and use `geom_text(label = column_with_labels)`

Comment: why did the `interaction` need to be adjusted? add a column to make sure the labels you need are lining up `melted_cormat$label <- with(melted_cormat, ifelse(Var1 == Var2, ages, ''))` and just use `geom_text(labels = melted_cormat$label)`

Comment: @rawr Yes, it should be so easy in theory but it is not. The line `Matrix$label <- with(...)` complicates http://paste.ubuntu.com/23413603/ at Line 4 and the error at the bottom. At the moment,  I cannot understand the case enough well to isolate the error better.

Comment: well since youre in the hadleyverse you would need `%>% mutate(label = ifelse(Var1 == Var2, ages, ''))` or something after you reshape (`gather`) into the ggplot data

Comment: @rawr It gives still `Error in eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()) :  numeric 'envir' arg not of length one Calls: makeMatrixPlot -> with -> with.default -> eval` with the `mutate` change before `gather`. Do you understand why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this instead (add your labels to the data object, and then use `geom_tile` and then `geom_text`)

```
gg <- ggplot(data = cbind(melted_cormat,ids, ages), 
             aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, fill=value)) +
        scale_x_discrete(labels = ids ) +
        scale_y_discrete(labels = ids)
 gg + geom_raster( aes(fill=value)) +
      geom_text(  aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, label = ages), color="red", size=3)
```

This brings the needed data into the naming environment where the gg-functions will be able to see those named columns. The geom_raster function builds an grid of cells to which attributes ("aesthetics") such as color or text can be added. By default it mimics the base-graphics function `image` upon which all of the heatmap-type functions derive by coloring with a color scale constructed using the range of the "fill"-aesthetic.

Output

[image]

Comment: This code is what I am working for the integration http://paste.ubuntu.com/23412503/ I am thinking how to integrate `geom_raster` there. How necessary is it?

Comment: Now we are back to the problem that you are not describing the 'Matrix' object (and not loading needed packages) and we won't know what we are working with. I'm certainly not the person to fix your buggy code deeply embedded in hadleyverse-dependencies.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Can you please describe the use of `geom_raster`. I want to understand better, so maybe, I can understand better then how to develop it for the target function and/or simplify it.

Comment: Your visualisation reveals that I have a design mistake in all the thing. Each cell has two ages corresponding to two IDs. Can this design extend for it? - - Such replicated values values would be most illustrative in the diagonal only once, because diagonal value is useless otherwise.

Comment: We seem to use the English language differently. You may need to pose a separate question with an illustration of what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Rawr's answer in comment for the diagonal visualisation

```
library("ggplot2")
library("reshape2")
mydata <- mtcars[, c(1,3,4,5,6,7)]
cormat <- round(cor(mydata),2)
melted_cormat <- melt(cormat)
ids = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6)
ages = c(11, 22, 33, 44, 55,66)

ggplot(data = melted_cormat, aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, fill=value)) + 
     geom_tile() + 
     geom_text(label = ifelse(melted_cormat$Var1 == melted_cormat$Var2, ages, ''))
```

Output

[image]

I cannot adjust the wiki answer and its `ifelse` to my real case where the following `geom-text` works

```
    geom_text(label = interaction(rep(ages, length(ages)), sep = ', ')) +
```